# how do I prevent unnecessary recomposition for my case?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

I have the following code for a Login screen which is contained in my NavHost:

```
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(
    loginViewModel: LoginViewModel = koinViewModel(),
    navController: NavController,
    showSnackbar: (String, SnackbarDuration) -> Unit
) {
    Timber.i("LoginScreen recomposed")
    val uiState by loginViewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
    val ssnInput = loginViewModel.ssnInput
    ScreenContent(
        isLoading = uiState.isLoading,
        userInput = ssnInput.takeIf { it.length !=  SSN_LENGTH } ?: stringResource(id = R.string.saved_ssn, ssnInput.substring(0, 8)),
        onInputValueChanged = { loginViewModel.updateSsnUserInput(it) },
        onLogInClick = { loginViewModel.sendBankIdRequest() },
        isSsnInvalid = uiState.error is InputError,
        onKeyboardDone = { },
        onClearClick = { loginViewModel.clearInputText() }
    )
    uiState.error?.let {
        val messageId = when (it) {
            InputError -> R.string.invalid_personal_number_format
            BankIdFailed -> R.string.bankid_failed_check_ssn
            NetworkError -> R.string.bankid_internal_error
            GenericError -> R.string.bankid_failed
            NoGMSError -> R.string.no_gms_error
        }
        showSnackbar(stringResource(id = messageId), SnackbarDuration.Short)
    }
}
```

Inside ScreenContent, I have a Box which contains an Image to use as a background for the screen and a Column which contains components (a title text, a custom text field, a login button, a read more clickable text and a logo image) that make up the rest of my screen. I created ScreenContent so that I could use it in the preview since it doesn't support ViewModels.

The problem I'm having is that whenever im clicking on the Login button which in turn calls `loginViewModel.sendBankIdRequest()`, uiState.error gets updated with InputError as value (which is what I want) and LoginScreen gets recomposed as a result, which causes showSnackbar to be called, which is the expected behavior when clicking the button. However, from this point onwards, LoginScreen gets recomposed every time `onInputValueChanged` lambda is called which happens whenever I enter or remove a character in the text field. This is causing the showSnackbar to be invoked every time due to recomposition, even though uiState has not been changed.

How do I solve this?

I can mitigate this by updating the uiState and setting error to null every time I update the text input value, but I don't see that as a solution. The solution I would like is for LoginScreen to not be recomposed unless uiState is changed. Changing the value of `userInput` parameter to `loginViewModel.ssnInput` without declaring it in ssnInput doesn't help either.